# W3C Validator error: "Error: CSS: background-image: is an incorrect operator."

Tags: validation, operator-keyword, w3c

I tested my code on the W3C validator and got an error I couldn't understand.
I simplified the code to get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .class{background-image: linear-gradient(red 0 110px, blue 110px 200px, yellow 300px)}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And received the following error:
Error: CSS: background-image:   is an incorrect operator.

At line 6, column 85

`x, yellow 300px)}↩</style>↩</h`

The closing bracket being highlighted.
I had a look in the explanations of the errors here (https://validator.w3.org/docs/errors.html) but didn't find anything.

Any idea of what's the issue (and how to solve it)?

Comment: That doesn't look like anything [explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML Validator uses the [CSS validator](https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/) under the hood to validate the content of `<style>` elements.

The construction you use for linear-gradient relies on the [multiple color stops](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#color-stop-syntax) syntax, which is defined in the level 4 of the CSS Image module, while I believe the CSS validator only implements up to [its level 3](https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/commit/bb3f651e8ce89943dce7b317531e80b0527e5aef).

Rewriting it as `linear-gradient(red 0, red 110px, blue 110px, blue 200px, yellow 300px)` should make it pass validation while obtaining the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, this change is considered acceptable.I din't know it was "advanced" syntax.